# Lost private key (keystore file)?

Tags: private-key, keystore

I am new in mining, so here's my story:
I installed Linux, downloaded geth and Claymore DualMiner.
Then generated a wallet address with geth (I was asked a passphrase) and started mining ETH ...

Meanwhile tried overclocking without success and decided to install windows + MSI Afterburner.

So .. I have wallet and passphrase and lost keystore file.

1. What to do to get my 0,2 ETH ?
2. Is it worth get the missing info (keystore file) or just start from the beginning?
3. What is the extension of that file?
4. What is in that file (maybe I can extract it with foremost like here: https://www.rissmann.ch/2014/08/09/how-to-recover-lost-files/)

I already lost 2 days to get my data back (undelete, testdisk, foremost).
I found some very old partitions and data, but what I seek was overwritten.

Please help ...

Answer (score 1):

## About the keystore file and specifications:

It is called: UTC JSON Keystore File

More info: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Accounts,_Addresses,_Public_And_Private_Keys,_And_Tokens

## I found my JSON file:

1. I put the HDD to another Linux machine
2. installed testdisk, listed my drives (the lost key was at /dev/sdc)
3. Then with:

> strings /dev/sdc | grep ea52e36ce9481bde98904d4307ba90cbc6cb8ac4

I got a mass amount of data, where I found a JSON like text:

> UTC--2017-06-27T23-00-32.157422930Z--ea52e36ce9481bde98904d4307ba90cbc6cb8ac4

followed with the content of key file.

The ea52e36ce9481bde98904d4307ba90cbc6cb8ac4 is my account.